# $\int_{x=0}^{100}\int_{y=0}^{100-x} \int_{z=0}^{100-x-y}(x+y+z)^{10} \mathrm dx \, \mathrm dy \, \mathrm dz$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

Is there any easy way to calculate the following

> $\int_{x=0}^{100}\int_{y=0}^{100-x} \int_{z=0}^{100-x-y}(x+y+z)^{10} \mathrm dz \,  \mathrm dy \, \mathrm dx$

and

> $\int_{x=0}^{100}\int_{y=0}^{100-x}
>  \int_{z=0}^{100-x-y}5\mathrm dz \,  \mathrm dy \, \mathrm dx$

Answer (score 2):

In both integrals it should be $dz dy dx$.

1. If $k$ is a constant, note that $\dfrac{d}{dz}\left(\frac{1}{11}(k+z)^{11}\right) = (k + z)^{10}$.
2. Note that $\iiint_V 5dV = 5\iiint 1dV = 5\operatorname{Vol}(V)$.

Answer (score 0):

For the second integral, yes:

This is simply $5$ times the volume of a the right triangular pyramid, or:
$$V=5\cdot\frac{1}{3}Ah=\frac{5}{6}100^3$$
For the first integral, you could look at $r = z+y+x$. Now the integrand is just the sum of the areas of the "slices" parallel to the equilateral triangle base, where each slice is at distance $r$ from the origin. Since each slice has constant $r$,
$$V=\int A_r \cdot r^{10} dr$$

Comment: I think he miswrote the order of integration--should be $dz dy dx$, which makes the inner most integral trivial.

Comment: What is $A_r$ and what is the range of $r$?

Comment: The limits are usually written as functions of the other variables. Since he had $z = 0$ as his lower bound and a function of $x$ and $y$ as the upper limit, I naturally assumed the inner most integral was with respect to $z$. Similarly for the outer two integrals.

Comment: @user46185 - $r$ is between 0 (the pyramid corner) and $H$ the pyramid height. As to $A_r$ it's really only a short bit of trig to find it. I'll try and post it later if I have time.